# Getting ASP.NET SAP Connector 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, sap-dotnet-connector

I need to use SAP Connector 3.0 for .NET. I was wondering if some of you know how to get it.

I have already installed the SAPMiddlewareConnector Package from NuGet but it doesn't seem to work. I get the following error:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression Status Warning
> The processor architecture of the project to be compiled "MSIL" and
> the processor architecture of the reference "sapnco_utils, Version =
> 3.0.0.42, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 50436dca5c7f7d23, processorArchitecture = x86", "x86", no coincide This mismatch can
> cause runtime errors. Change the architecture of the target processor
> of the project using the Configuration Manager to align the processor
> architectures between the project and the references, or take a
> dependency on the references with a processor architecture that
> matches the architecture of the target processor of the project .
> SAPConector

I think the solution for this problem is to get the proper sapnco.dll and all related sap dll needed to connect.

I am compiling in .NET Framework 4.5, I Allready tried complinig in different versions without good result.

I have 64bit windows 10.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are licensed for it you should be able to download it from the SAP service marketplace.